# Libgdx Scaling coordinates for different devices

Tags: java, libgdx

I have made a simple game where you click on a object and it should dissapear. It works fine on desktop with the dimensions 240 x 480 but on my phone the dimensions are wider like 1920 x 1080 so the touch down coordinates are different so on desktop it might log the touch 100 x 50 but if i tapped the same place on phone it would be 400 x 200 so i just want to scale them or use the same.

```
private double WidthScale = (272 / Gdx.graphics.getWidth());
private double HeightScale = (408 / Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

private Array<Rectangle> rockets;
private long lastDropTime = 0;

private float tap_X = 0;
private float tap_Y = 0;

public GameRenderer() {
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false, 408, 272);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    rockets = new Array<Rectangle>();
    spawnRocket();
}

public void render(){
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    cam.update();

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

    batch.begin();
    for(Rectangle rocket : rockets) {
        batch.draw(AssetLoader.rocket ,rocket.x, rocket.y,
                rocket.width, rocket.height);
    }
    batch.end();

    if (Gdx.input.justTouched()){
        tap_X = (int) (Gdx.input.getX() * HeightScale);
        tap_Y = (int) ((Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.input.getY()) * WidthScale);

        Gdx.app.log("MyTag", String.valueOf(tap_X));
        Gdx.app.log("MyTag", String.valueOf(tap_Y));
        Gdx.app.log("MyTag", String.valueOf(HeightScale));
        Gdx.app.log("MyTag", String.valueOf(WidthScale));
    }

    Iterator<Rectangle> iter = rockets.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        Rectangle rocket = iter.next();
        rocket.y -= 70 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if(rocket.y + 32 < 0) iter.remove();

        if (rocket.x < tap_X && tap_X < rocket.x + rocket.width) {
            Gdx.app.log("MyTag", "getRekt");
            if (tap_Y > rocket.y && tap_Y < rocket.y + rocket.height) {
                Gdx.app.log("MyTag", "poo");
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000) spawnRocket();
}

private void spawnRocket() {
    Gdx.app.log("MyTag", "Rocket Spawned");
    Rectangle rocket = new Rectangle();
    rocket.x = MathUtils.random(0 , 272 - 16);
    rocket.y = 408 + rocket.height;
    rocket.height = 32;
    rocket.width = 16;
    rockets.add(rocket);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}
```

Comment: you have to deal with different viewports and projections, add the code to know what have you tried and what are you expecting...

Comment: @AlexandroSifuentesDíaz Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to work with different screen sizes, you have to deal with viewports, there's an [entirely section in libGDX wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) that shows how to work with it. A fast example could be the following (however, I suggest to read the wiki and try others viewports by yourself):

```
// Declare a viewport object
private Viewport v;

public GameRenderer() {
    // initialize after your camera initialization
    v = new FitViewport(408, 272, cam); // <- I have use a FitViewport 
                                        //    but you can use others
    // I guess you could remove the setToOrtho() but not too sure...
    // ... rest of code
}
```

*You have to properly dispose and update this object* *

A thing you should consider is, when you use something like `Gdx.input.getX()` you are getting a screen current position, you have to transform this coordinate system to your world coordinate system. Wherever you use something like that you have to do the following:

```
Vector3 v = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
v = cam.unproject(v);
// now v has your coordinate world system and you can properly make use of it
// you can do now something like:
tap_x = (int) v.x;
tap_y = (int) v.y;
```

Hope you find this useful.